# Ionic http CORS same origin not allowed

Tags: ionic-framework, cors, mailgun

I'm trying to set a [Mailgun mail service](http://www.mailgun.com/) in an ionic app. Here is the code:
Controller:

```
$http({
                        "method": "POST",
                        "url": "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + mailgunUrl + "/messages",
                        //"crossDomain": "true",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",//"http://localhost:8100",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "content-type, accept",
                            //"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
                            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                            'Authorization' : 'Basic '+ mailgunApiKey
                            //"Authorization": "Basic " + mailgunApiKey//$base64.encode('api:key-'+mailgunApiKey)
                        },
                        data: "from=" + "no-reply@ineevent.com" + "&to=" + $scope.datapopup.mail + "&subject=" + "Guestlist" + "&text="
```

config.xml

```
<content src="main.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crop" spec="~0.1.0"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
```

I receive the `status '0' error` and the logs show that CORS (Cross-Origin request) is not allowed with access-control-allow-headers missing (translated from french).

Another error from Chrome is `'Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.'`.

I tried also from android device but is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to index.html

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

and add [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) plugin to your app.

---

For the purpose of development you can use [CORS plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) for Chrome.

---

Your controller can be like this:

```
.controller("EmailCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    var mailgunUrl = "YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE";
    var mailgunApiKey = window.btoa("api:key-YOUR_API_KEY_HERE")

    $scope.recipient = "mail@gmail.com";

    $scope.send = function(recipient, subject, message) {
        $http(
            {
                "method": "POST",
                "url": "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + mailgunUrl + "/messages",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + mailgunApiKey
                },
                data: "from=" + "ionic@example.com" + "&to=" + recipient + "&subject=" + subject + "&text=" + message
            }
        ).then(function(success) {
            console.log("SUCCESS " + JSON.stringify(success));
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("ERROR " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }

})
```

Comment: I see you've found a solution :) . I wrote a blog post about Mailgun and Ionic few months ago so I know it has to work. @NightSkyCode ?

Comment: Why downvotes https://postimg.cc/image/h6yuq3ir5/ for 4 of my answers? For answer above still can be understand, but not for my other answers. First comment from NightSkyCode is about someone being a jerk. That's why I put a question mark by his nickname because it was not clear to whom he was referring. Ass I can see account for NightSkyCode http://stackoverflow.com/users/1530143/nightskycode is suspended "This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends on Sep 1 at 15:41."

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple:

when you run android from ionic you shouldn't use any optional parameter:
ionic run android